# PHP round() 0.50 to lower value

Tags: php, numbers, rounding

is there any way you can round to lower with any number lower than .50 including .50?

For example:

```
round(1.49) => 1

round(1.51) => 2

round(1.50) => 2
```

Is there any way to make it like this:

```
round(1.49) => 1

round(1.51) => 2

round(1.50) => 1
```

Comment: Yes, using the `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` flag for [round()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` flag

```
echo round(1.49, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
echo PHP_EOL;
echo round(1.50, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
echo PHP_EOL;
echo round(1.51, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

Comment: It's all about [good documentation](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php#refsect1-function.round-parameters) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Subtract 0.5 from your number and use `ceil` on the result.

E.g. `ceil(1.51 - 0.5) = 2`, `ceil(1.50 - 0.5) = 1`

It's a perversion of the idiomatic way of doing rounding without a `round` function. The subtraction caters for your wanting to round the 1/2 way point downwards. Extra checks necessary for negatives.